# How many members are needed to review a late answer entry?

Tags: discussion

Entries of different review queues need to be reviewed by one or more members.

How many members are needed to review a late answer entry?

Comment: Based on my history, it seems only one vote is needed.

Comment: Why don't you think so?

Comment: I think it is supposed to be done by one member just like for *First Posts* queue entries. But sometimes I noticed the same late answer reviewed within the same queue twice.

Answer (score 5):

One vote is *sufficient*, but SE does not *forbid* more votes.

In other words, when two people access the same pending review, SE will not reject one vote under the pretext that someone else has voted just before you. As long as you access the pending review when it is open, your vote will be taken into account.

This is why, while most reviews are closed with only one vote, there are some occurrences showing two votes separated by just a few minutes.

Comment: Quite logic what you said. Thank you. But sometimes I reviewed a late answer which later (an hour or more later),  is reviewed again as a late answer  (instead of a low quality post only), whereas 99.99% of late answers are reviewed only once (within the late answers queue). In fact, for the moment only one member is able to trick the system and do that (but I won't mention him :) so I wonder if there's a *bug* one succeeded to *exploit*.

Comment: The most obvious way I see to trick such system would be to automatically open a new tab on each new pending review as soon as it appears and leave it opened until the malicious user validates the review. The most obvious counter-measure would be to set a timeout after which the second user could not validate his review even if he accessed it while it was still open (no one needs to think during one hour before validating a single review ;) !), but I do not know if SE implemented such a thing... good question !